# Jenkins - Parameterized Builds & SCM Trigger/Schedule

Tags: msbuild, build, jenkins, mstest, parameterized

We have a build that among other things, runs MSTest.  We have separated some tests into "Nightly" and everything else, to keep our build running quickly.

We want:

- On SCM change trigger, run all uncategorized tests
- On nightly schedule, run all tests including "Nightly" category

I was setting this up with parameterized builds, but there isn't an option to select parameters on SCM change or on a schedule.

Is there a workaround to make this work?  Maybe using a second build project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with 2 projects:

- My original project is setup with SCM trigger, running the "Fast" category only
- Setup a second project with a scheduled nightly trigger, its only build step is to trigger the first project running both "Fast" and "Slow categories.